Printing from Windows Docker container
I'm trying to create a Windows based container to host a service that can print.
My container host is Windows Server 2022. I have the latest Docker Desktop installed and use this to build the image:
docker build -t my-app-server-image .

and this to run the container:
docker run --rm --network nat --name my-container --hostname my-docker --isolation=hyperv -it my-app-server-image cmd

Here is the relevant part of the docker file. The steps for installing my app have been omitted:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/server:ltsc2022
SHELL ["cmd", "/S", "/C"]

#...install my app...

RUN powershell -Command \
Add-PrinterPort -Name '192.168.21.75' -PrinterHostAddress '192.168.21.75';
Add-PrinterDriver -Name 'Generic / Text Only' -InfPath 'C:\windows\inf\prnge001.inf'; \
Add-Printer -Name 'PM45' -DriverName 'Generic / Text Only' -PortName '192.168.21.75';
Add-PrinterPort -Name '192.168.20.36' -PrinterHostAddress '192.168.20.36'; 
Add-PrinterDriver -Name 'Microsoft PCL6 Class Driver' -InfPath 'C:\windows\inf\prnms005.inf'; 
Add-Printer -Name HP4 -DriverName 'Microsoft PCL6 Class Driver' -PortName '192.168.20.36';

This fails on the last line ("Add-Printer -Name HP4...") with error:

"Add-Printer: An error occurred while performing the specified operation.  See the error details for more information."

But of course, there are no error details.
The PM45 printer is created successfully, and I can print with it in the container if I build the image without attempting to create the HP4 printer.
I have tried combinations of creating the port as a local port, or TCP port, referring directly to the printer (by IP address as shown above), or referring to a print queue on an intermediate print server. I've tried using the "Microsoft enhanced Point and Print compatibility driver" and "Microsoft IPP Class Driver" (the printer supports IPP printing and is so configured).
I've tried these various combinations from a non-container and been successful creating the printer and printing. There is something about a Windows container that is blocking me.
I've searched the web for info on printing from a Windows container. Here is one reference from Microsoft that seems to suggest it is possible:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deploy-containers/print-spooler
But have had only limited success.
If anyone has been able to create a printer in a Windows container and print something other than a plain text document, I would love to hear how you did it.
